# JMeter freezes when you run the test from remote server

Tags: jmeter

1. On my remote host I am running jmeter server 
   ./jmeter-server
2. I have kicked the jmeter from my local machine using this command 
   ./jmeter -Jremote_hosts=Remote Host IP
3. GUI Pops up
4. Open my test.jmx and Run->RemoteHost->RemoteHostIP
5. At this time, jmeter freezes, I was unable to do much after that 
   my test had 1 thread, 60secs ramp, run 1 time

Any idea why is it frozen and I am not be see any test results. I do not have any listeners except "View Results Tree"

Comment: are both remote host & jmeter (local) in the same subnet?

Comment: did you follow the guide to set it up? - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf
Check firewalls

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. In my case, it was due to the firewall (ufw on ubuntu). After stopping the firewall I was able to run the tests normally.